# RECORDS OMITTED FROM QUERY USING JPAPAGINGITEMREADER while reading

Tags: spring-batch

```
<batch:job id="xyzJob" job-repository="jobRepository"
    incrementer="jobParametersIncrementerImpl" restartable="false">
    <batch:step id="feeStep">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <batch:chunk reader="xyzReader" processor="xyzProcessor"
                writer="xyzWriter" commit-interval="4" >
                <batch:streams>
                    <batch:stream ref="fileWriter"/>
                </batch:streams>
            </batch:chunk>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="stepExecutionListener"/>
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="xyzJobListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>

<bean id="xyzProcessor" class="com.batch.core.processor.XYZProcessor" scope="step">
    <property name="fundDAO" ref="fundDAO"/>
    <property name="loanDAO" ref="loanDAO"/>
    <property name="aumBlnceDAO" ref="aumBalanceDAO"/>
    ---
    --
</bean> 


<bean id="xyzWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter">
        <property name="delegates">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.batch.core.writer.xyzWriter">
                        <property name="xyzDetailsDomain" ref="xyzDetailsDomain" />
                        <property name="xyzHistoryDomain" ref="xyzHistoryDomain"></property>
                </bean>
                <ref bean="fileWriter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="xyzReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader" scope="step">  
   <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="batchEntityManagerFactoryBean"/> 
   <property name="queryString"> 
      <value><![CDATA[
              SELECT pe, pap 
              FROM A pe, B pap 
              WHERE pap.userID =pe.userID and pe.status = 'E' 
              and pe.startDT <= '#{jobExecutionContext[previousQuarterEndDate]}' 
              and (pe.endDT is null 
              or pe.endDT > '#{jobExecutionContext[previousQuarterEndDate]}')]]>
       </value>
   </property>  
   <property name="pageSize" value="1000"/> 
   <property name="saveState" value="false" /> 
</bean>
```

When this spring batch is running what I have noticed sometimes its skipped some records while reading data from tables .. this issue not consistent... but out of 10 times it may occur 1 time.

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: <bean id="xyzReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader" scope="step"> <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="batchEntityManagerFactoryBean"/>
   <property name="queryString">
<value><![CDATA[SELECT pe, pap FROM A pe, B pap WHERE pap.userID =pe.userID and pe.status = 'E' and pe.startDT <= '#{jobExecutionContext[previousQuarterEndDate]}' and (pe.endDT is null or pe.endDT > '#{jobExecutionContext[previousQuarterEndDate]}')]]></value>
  </property>     
      <property name="pageSize" value="1000"/>
   <property name="saveState" value="false" />
 </bean>

Comment: please remove the code in the comment and add it to the question.

Comment: Above reader code was missing in question

Comment: I edited the question and added the code of the reader you provided. Please don't put code in comments as this is not readable. You can always edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `JpaPagingItemReader` does not skip records. What is probably happening in your case is that some records corresponding to your search criteria are added while your reader is reading data. This may lead to wrong page calculation and some items may seem to be skipped but it is not the case.

A batch processing job is by definition acting on a *fixed* data set. If your query returns a fixed data set while your job is running, the same pages should be returned for each run of your job. If on the other hand another process inserts data that can be returned by your query, then your issue can happen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply..!! Issue was happening because in job configuration pageSize was 100 and the interval-commit=4. 
When I changed it to the same number 4000 (Since all records were less than this) so in one read reader will read all the records and processed without going control out of processor and at the end commit happened once all record processed.

Comment: Setting `pageSize=commitInterval` should give better performance (See [Javadoc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReader.java#L55-L56)). However, even with page size != commit interval, there should be no records skipped.